# Python Looping through input().split()

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input

I'm trying to write a code that verifies the if password entered matches the criteria given below.

---

1. At least 1 letter between [a-z]
2. At least 1 number between [0-9]
3. At least 1 letter between [A-Z]
4. At least 1 character from [$#@]
5. Minimum length of transaction password: 6
6. Maximum length of transaction password: 12

   ---

[Output and code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iUwl.png)

```
import re
tmp=[]
for i in input().split(','):
  print(i)
  upp=0
  low=0
  dig=0
  sch=0
  for j in i:
    if j.isdigit() and dig!=1:
      dig=1
    elif j.isupper() and upp!=1:
      upp=1
    elif j.islower() and low!=1:
      low=1
    elif re.search("[$#@]",j) and sch!=1:
      sch=1
    elif dig and sch and low and upp and (len(i)>=6 and len(i)<=12)==True:
      tmp+=[i]
      print(i)
      print(tmp)
print(','.join(tmp))
```

The test case is

> This@me1,notThis,Fine@3456,&1234567sdfD

It seems like its looping through one of the test cases thrice?

The output looks like :

```
This@me1
notThis
Fine@3456
Fine@3456
['Fine@3456']
Fine@3456
['Fine@3456', 'Fine@3456']
Fine@3456
['Fine@3456', 'Fine@3456', 'Fine@3456']
&1234567sdfD
Fine@3456,Fine@3456,Fine@3456
```

Not entirely sure what is causing this. Why is it running the Fine@3456 case thrice? Also, I fail to understand why the first case This@me1 also does not get recognized as valid.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Note: I'm running this code online-on repl.it: https://IroncladSoulfulKiskadee.yashvedi.repl.run <- To run the test case

Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

ps. Please ignore the redundancy in the code;

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elif dig and sch and low and upp and (len(i)>=6 and len(i)<=12)==True:
  tmp+=[i]
```

This is not happening in the right place. Consider the password `This@me1`. At the last iteration of the inner loop, will we execute

```
if j.isdigit() and dig!=1:
  dig=1
```

And then none of the `elif` stuff goes through (including your final check).

The issue with `Fine@3456` running three times is due to a very similar problem.

To fix:

```
for j in i:
    if j.isdigit() and dig!=1:
      dig=1
    elif j.isupper() and upp!=1:
      upp=1
    elif j.islower() and low!=1:
      low=1
    elif re.search("[$#@]",j) and sch!=1:
      sch=1
if dig and sch and low and upp and (len(i)>=6 and len(i)<=12)==True:
  tmp+=[i]
```

Check if the condition holds after you've checked everything.

(And consider using `True` and `False` instead of `1` and `0`. That's why they're there.)

Comment: Ah Hah!, You mean it moves out of the loop before checking the final condition!
That makes sense.
Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Fine@3456 verifies the same condition since its looping through the string-thrice after initial verification

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of checking all words characters in a loop do something like this (Its more readable):

```
import re
tmp=[]
for i in input().split(','):
  if not (6 <= len(i) <= 12):
    continue
  if not re.search("[$#@]", i):
    continue
  if not re.search("[a-z]", i):
    continue
  if not re.search("[A-Z]", i):
    continue
  if not re.search("[0-9]", i):
    continue
  tmp.append(i)
print(','.join(tmp))
```

Comment: Hello,
That looks so much better. Thanks, I'll surely take this approach next time.